# Prove that there is a function $w > 0$ such that $\int_{0}^{1}w(x) dx \neq 0$ and $\frac{\int_{0}^{1}w(x)x^{2}dx}{\int_{0}^{1}w(x)dx} = \frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I can see that $w(x) := x$ on $]0, \infty[$ suffices, but I am after a systematic analysis to see this, which I am incapable to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a broad class of function, let

$w(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty w_kx^k$

so that

$\int_0^1 w(x)\,x^m=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k+m+1}w_k.$

Multiplying by the denominator integral of your condition equation, $\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{k+1}$ is popping up on the left hand side. So you need to solve

$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{k+m+1}-\frac{1}{k+(k+1)+1}\right)w_k=0$

for $w_k$'s.

The term with $k=m-1$ is zero for free, so $w_{m-1}$ is without condition. For your case of $m=2$, you might set all other $w_k\neq w_1$ zero and find your solution of $w(x)=w_1x$.

---

Answer to the comment:

Here is another example solution obtained via the above formulation. 
Just set

$w_k=\dfrac{(-1)^k}{\frac{1}{k+m+1}-\frac{1}{k+(k+1)+1}}$

and sum up an even number of terms. (Ensuring positivity will be more work.)

For example, the solution for

$0+0+0+1-1+1-1=0$

obtained this way is $w(x)=-378 x^6+360 x^5-350 x^4+360 x^3$.

(I've multiplied by $-15$ to make all coefficients integers.)

[image]

Comment: how would you justify interchanging the infinite sum and the integral?

Comment: Thanks very much for taking time to write. Is it necessary to employ infinite series? Would considering $w(x) := x^{n}$ for some integer $n$ suffice?

Comment: @GregVoit: OP didn't specify the function space of his "systematic analysis". It's a huge class of function, e.g. it works *at least* whenever the sum is finite.

Comment: @YLChou: I've just chose a big and easy to handle function space. I've now added a recipe to the answer, to find solutions of arbitrary combinations of $x^m$'s.

Answer (score 2):

Try $w(x)=x^2+a$. One adjustable parameter is enough.

$$\int_0^1(x^2+a)x^2\,dx=\frac15+\frac a3,$$
$$\int_0^1(x^2+a)\,dx=\frac13+a$$

then
$$\frac15+\frac a3=\frac16+\frac a2.$$

Solution:
$$w(x)=x^2+\frac15.$$

Comment: I first tried $w(x)=x+a$ which resulted in $w(x)=x$, unfortunately not $>0$ everywhere. Using a different balance of the weights helps getting a positive expression. Sorry for the empirism.

Answer (score 2):

This is sort of a linear algebra problem.

Consider the vector space of square-integrable functions on $[0,1]$ with the inner product $\left<f,g\right> = \int_0^1 f(x)g(x)\,\mathrm dx$. You are basically looking for a function $w$ such that $$\frac {\left<w,a\right>}{\left<w,b\right>} = \frac 1 2$$
where $a(x)=x^2$ and $b(x)=1$. Note that $$\left<a,a\right> = \int_0^1x^4\,\mathrm dx=\frac 15\\\left<a,b\right> = \int_0^1 x^2\,\mathrm dx=\frac 1 3\\\left<b,b\right> = \int_0^11\,\mathrm dx =1$$

Let's guess that we can satisfy this with a linear combination of $a$ and $b$, that is, $w = \alpha a + \beta b$. Then we get$$\left<w,a\right> = \alpha\left<a,a\right> + \beta\left<a,b\right> = \frac 15 \alpha + \frac 1 3 \beta\\\left<w,b\right> = \alpha\left<a,b\right> + \beta\left<b,b\right> = \frac 1 3 \alpha + \beta$$

Okay, so you want $$\frac{\frac 1 5\alpha + \frac 1 3 \beta}{\frac 1 3 \alpha +  \beta} = \frac 1 2$$ i.e. $$\alpha = 5\beta$$ and that's it. Choose, for example, $\alpha = 1, \beta = 5$. Of course, other functions can be chosen.

Answer (score 2):

We can use $w(x)=\alpha x^{\alpha-1}$ for $\alpha\gt0$. Then
$$
\int_0^1w(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=1
$$
and
$$
\int_0^1w(x)\,x^2\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+2}
$$
By adjusting $\alpha\gt0$, we can get
$$
\frac{\int_0^1w(x)\,x^2\,\mathrm{d}x}{\int_0^1w(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+2}
$$
to be anything in $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Not a rigorous answer (without putting in extra work, at least), but IMO a good way to convince yourself that there must indeed be such a function. To my mind, this argument (when suitably formalized) is actually **more** satisfying than just an example of such a function:

- On the one hand ($w(x)=1$) we have ${\int_0^1x^2dx\over \int_0^1 1dx}={1\over 3}<{1\over 2}.$
- On the other hand ($w(x)=x^{100}$) we have ${\int_0^1x^{102}dx\over\int_0^1x^{100}dx}={{1\over 103}\over {1\over 101}}>{1\over 2}$. (How did we know to choose something like this for $w$? Well, first of all polynomials are easy to integrate; second, polynomials with high exponent are "very far" from constant functions, and we already did a constant function. This same reasoning could have also led us to try $w(x)=e^x$, but $x^2e^x$ is annoying to integrate.)
- So now we apply a kind of intermediate value theorem: if we imagine continuously deforming the function $x\mapsto 1$ into the function $x\mapsto x^{100}$, at some point we should get a $w$ satisfying the desired formula.

Of course, all the meat is hidden in this last step - how do we know that the function $w\mapsto {\int_0^1x^2w(x)dx\over \int_0^1 w(x)dx}$ is continuous on the relevant space of functions? and how do we know that space is connected? - so this isn't a proof at all. But it's a good plausibility argument.

---

OKAY FINE technically these don't really satisfy the demand "$w(x)>0$" since in all the examples above, $w(0)=0$; but this is easily dealt with.

Comment: Best of all, if you spend some time trying to make this precise, you'll find yourself accidentally discovering topology and function spaces! :D Also homotopy, for that matter, if you approach the issue of connectedness in the right way.

Comment: Thank you so much for the extension. I can feel the implied excitement! But I guess I am not that good at the present stage to discover that like you did.

Answer (score 1):

How about

1. $w(x)=\frac{b}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ for $b>0$
2. $w(x)=\frac{6x-5x^3}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$
3. $w(x)=\frac{1+10x^2-10x^4}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

And also note that for $\displaystyle w_n(x)=\frac{(x+\sqrt{1-x^2})^n-(x-\sqrt{1-x^2})^n}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ we have that $$\int_0^1w_{2n}(x)(x^2-\frac12)dx=0 , n=1,2,3,...$$ and $$\int_0^1w_{2n-1}(x)(x^2-\frac12)dx=-\frac{1}{2n+3}, n=1,2,3,...$$
implying that 
$$\frac{\int_0^1x^2w_{2n}(x)dx}{\int_0^1w_{2n}(x)dx}=\frac12.$$
Note that $w_{2n}(x)$ is positive on the interval of integration.